# Styling a ReactJS created table (Score Matrix)

Tags: css, reactjs, less

Just learning react and would like to be able to make something like this:

[image]

I got so far:

```js
  class ScoreMatrixRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let rown = this.props.RowNumber;
    let colN = this.props.Columns;
    let factor = this.props.Factor;
    var cells = _.range(1, colN+1).map( (i) => {
      
      let cellVal = (i)*rown*factor;
      let style = {backgroundColor: 'gold'};
      if (cellVal < this.props.LowLimit) {
        style = {backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'};
      } else if (cellVal > this.props.HighLimit){
        style = {backgroundColor: 'indianred'};
      } 
      
      let key = `R${rown}C${i}`;
      if (key == this.props.ScoreLocation) {
        style = {...style, color: "blue"};
      }
      
      return <td key={key} style={style}>{cellVal}</td>
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {cells}
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class ScoreMatrix extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let rows = _.range(1, this.props.Rows+1).reverse();
    
    return (
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tbody>
          {rows.map( r => 
                    <ScoreMatrixRow 
                      RowNumber={r} 
                      Columns={this.props.Columns}
                      Factor={this.props.Factor}
                      LowLimit={this.props.LowLimit}
                      HighLimit={this.props.HighLimit}
                      ScoreLocation = {this.props.ScoreLocation}
                      /> )}
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <ScoreMatrix Rows={3} Columns={3} Factor={2} LowLimit={5} HighLimit={11} ScoreLocation="R3C1" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
body {
    padding: 5px
}

   td {
padding: 15px
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

I'm not the best at CSS and need some help on how to style a table like this. I don't mind using bootstrap - I just don't know how to do it (the class and className makes it a bit more difficult for me).

It doesn't have to look as boring as my example. I would like to change the `Factor` and `ScoreLocation` with some cool fade transitions..

---

## Update

Got a little bit closer to the target..

```js
class ScoreMatrixRow extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let rown = this.props.RowNumber;
    let colN = this.props.Columns;
    let factor = this.props.Factor;
    var cells = _.range(1, colN+1).map( (i) => {
      
      let cellVal = (i)*rown*factor;
      let style = {backgroundColor: 'gold'};
      if (cellVal < this.props.LowLimit) {
        style = {backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'};
      } else if (cellVal > this.props.HighLimit){
        style = {backgroundColor: 'indianred'};
      } 
      
      let key = `R${rown}C${i}`;
      let classTag = "normal";
      if (key == this.props.ScoreLocation) {
        style = {...style, color: "white"};
        classTag = "selected";
      }
      
      return (
        <td key={key} style={style}>
          <span className={classTag}> {cellVal} </span>
        </td>)
    });
    return (
      <tr>
        {cells}
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

class ScoreMatrix extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let rows = _.range(1, this.props.Rows+1).reverse();
    
    return (
      <table >
        <tbody>
          {rows.map( r => 
                    <ScoreMatrixRow 
                      RowNumber={r} 
                      Columns={this.props.Columns}
                      Factor={this.props.Factor}
                      LowLimit={this.props.LowLimit}
                      HighLimit={this.props.HighLimit}
                      ScoreLocation = {this.props.ScoreLocation}
                      /> )}
          
        </tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(
  <ScoreMatrix Rows={3} Columns={3} Factor={2} LowLimit={5} HighLimit={11} ScoreLocation="R3C1" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
body {
    padding: 10px
}

td {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
}

td .selected {
    padding: 0.4em 0.7em; 
    border-radius: 1em; 
    background: blue;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 -moz-border-radius: 25px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
 border-radius: 25px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: To get a bigger circle around the selected number, wrap it in a span with nonzero padding (something like `padding: 0.4em 0.7em; border-radius: 1em; background: blue;`). For fade transitions, just add `transition: all 0.5s ease` or similar.

Comment: @sebastian_k thank you. I updated the question.

Comment: It looks like you've already achieved what you set out to do – what more do you need?

Comment: You are right. I can't set the question to answered because there is no answer post, only comments. If you post your commment as an answer then I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: I still hope that somebody have a boostrap or other CSS trick that makes it looks much more stylish 